# THREE.js - Switching LODs based on result some function

Tags: three.js

I am using THREE.js via this - https://github.com/ubilabs/google-maps-api-threejs-layer and I would like to implement custom logic for switching LODs. The main reason is that distance from camera is still the same but camera have scale set based on zoom level of map. I would like to switch LOD based on zoom level. I am trying to figure out how to "hack" LOD logic so I could pass own function which will be called by THREE.js and will return which LOD to use.

Please can you give me some hints how to implement this in the way as clean as possible?